# Jquery - How to call a function only if a new row is inserted in database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a div which contains comments for a post ... when user add a comment the div containing comments get updated immediately ( i have set a function which is called when user press enter )
Here Is my code for that :

```
$(document).on('keydown','.addComment',function(e){
var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
var p_id = Number(id);
var comment_box = '#comment_box_'+id;
var content = $(comment_box).text();

if (e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey !== true) {

    content = content.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    if (content.length > 0  ) {

        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update.php',
            data: ({
                content: content,
                id: p_id,
                act: "add_cmnt"
            }),
            success : function()
            {
                update_ca("comment_area_"+id, true);
            }
        }); //End of Ajax
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

but a user logged in from another account must have to refresh the page to see new comments ...  now what i want to do is that all users see the latest comments without refreshing the page i.e when ever a new comment is posted by any user the div containing comments should be updated ... now one way is to do this is that a function is called out after every 10 seconds which refreshes the div via ajax 
Here is code :

```
setInterval(function(){update_comment_area();}, 10000);
```

this line of code refreshes the comment area after every 10 seconds but i want this function to be called  only if a new row ( comment ) is inserted into a database 
can anyone help me that how this can be done ??

Comment: Your question is too generic. You should specify what technologies you are using such as program languages, database, server, messaging engine, etc...

Comment: Add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: please excuse me ... i really don't have any idea that how to ask my question ... can you suggest me what should i have to provide in support of my question please ?

Comment: I think I get your point. You have to use something like websockets and sent the update that has been done in the database to all the other users.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you already have an event for the submission of a comment, and assuming you're using javascript to push the comment to the server:

You can just use a callback and have it refresh then. Of course, that would only show up for the user that submitted the comment.

Example for that: [JQuery Ajax calls with callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Since you haven't mentioned your back-end coding language or database structure there are only a limited amount of suggestions I can give. However, one that would work would be to use AngularJS, or Socket.io to establish 2-way binding.

UPDATE:

Based on your code and how you're calling it I'm going to assume that update.php has the ability to know whether the record (comment) was added successfully. Once it's been added, have update.php set a global javascript variable to a new value (increment it, use a random number, doesn't matter as long as the value changes)

Then setup an `object.watch()` that will do your ajax call to update the comments when that variable changes. This is probably the simplest way to do it without using something like socket.io or angular.

[How to use object.watch in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

Comment: please excuse me ... i really don't have any idea that how to ask my question ... can you suggest me what should i have to provide in support of my question please ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that checks for a new row in the database i.e checkNew().

Then try:

```
if (checkNew()) {
   refreshAjax();
}
```

Note: for the checkNew(), if a new record has been inputted, return true; 
Else return false;

Comment: The checkNew() function is going to be hard to implement so you can just keep refreshing the page

Comment: but how to check that if new record is insertd into database ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to implement the checkNow():
Let it retrieve the value gotten from a PHP page that performs the SQL: `SELECT lastupdated FROM commentTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1.`

What that does is that it retrieves the last value in the commentTable which would obviously be the last inserted comment. Then update your page with intervals. The comment will continue to change as long as more comments are being added

Comment: You should edit your original answer instead of adding an additional answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to take note next time